# how to get the ip address of https requests made from the JVM without changing the code base

Tags: java, logging, jvm, log4j

Currently I am supporting a production application which makes a rest call to an external site. This site is called with an url , let say foreignapi.com, and this host does not have a static api, it changes ,and the provider adds new IP  every now and then.  I would like to keep an inventory of these IP's . but unfortunately I cannot change the code , I have to achieve this goal using whatever the JVM brings, or configuration change like logging properties.
so far in my research I have found that I could enable HttpURLConnection debug logging, but unfortunately this is not outputting the ip.

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINEST
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.level = ALL
```

here is the output of the previous approach if I set the logging level to TRACE

```
2022-04-05 18:44:13.539 TRACE 43344 --- [           main] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : ProxySelector Request for https://stackoverflow.com/
2022-04-05 18:44:13.540 TRACE 43344 --- [           main] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : Looking for HttpClient for URL https://stackoverflow.com and proxy value of DIRECT
2022-04-05 18:44:13.540 TRACE 43344 --- [           main] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : Creating new HttpsClient with url:https://stackoverflow.com and proxy:DIRECT with connect timeout:-1
2022-04-05 18:44:13.622 TRACE 43344 --- [           main] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : Proxy used: DIRECT
2022-04-05 18:44:13.769 DEBUG 43344 --- [           main] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : sun.net.www.MessageHeader@76c387f95 pairs: {GET / HTTP/1.1: null}{User-Agent: Java/17.0.2}{Host: stackoverflow.com}{Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2}{Connection: keep-alive}
2022-04-05 18:44:13.906 DEBUG 43344 --- [           main] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : sun.net.www.MessageHeader@1976f53720 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 200 OK}{Connection: keep-alive}{cache-control: private}{content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8}{strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000}{x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN}{x-request-guid: e8e59f65-0ef0-453b-8021-34d74a4aa7a4}{feature-policy: microphone 'none'; speaker 'none'}{content-security-policy: upgrade-insecure-requests; frame-ancestors 'self' https://stackexchange.com}{Accept-Ranges: bytes}{Date: Tue, 05 Apr 2022 23:44:14 GMT}{Via: 1.1 varnish}{X-Served-By: cache-sna10750-LGB}{X-Cache: MISS}{X-Cache-Hits: 0}{X-Timer: S1649202254.025882,VS0,VE75}{Vary: Fastly-SSL}{X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off}{Set-Cookie: prov=222f077a-0b7b-25cc-fa73-ee9846242ae7; domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly}{transfer-encoding: chunked}
```

I hope someone in the community could shed some light here, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about internal java httpclient logs, but Apache HttpClient definitely logs IPs / hostnames - but it seems you are not using that.

You could use an external program to capture the traffic though - `tcpdump` for example can capture such things naturally.

```
sudo tcpdump -v -nni any ip host foreignapi.com
```

There are other tools available to capture process network traffic like `ngrep` or DNS queries specifically (`dnspeep`, `gethostlatency-bpfcc`, etc.)

Using an external tool might not be the best solution if you need to run it continuously but in that case, I would question the inability to modify the code (since you obviously can change the logging configuration).